# Disable refresh icon of chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Can we disable the refresh icon of Chrome browser using jQuery/JavaScript? I was able to disable refresh using F5 but not using the refresh icon. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In short, No. Also, if you could this would be a pretty bad practice. You might try using window.onbeforeunload to work around your issue.

Comment: Don't do this. The browser is mine, and I want the refresh button to work.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: No, because allowing websites to disable browser controls could cause all sorts of bad consequences and allow hijacking the browser or holding it hostage. The best you can do is prompt the user and confirm their action, as indicated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21091401/2057919).

Also, FYI, it is a refresh button, not an icon.

Comment: Even longer answer: **No.** You should never mess with default browser controls, save for a very few scenarios where it makes sense (e.g. contextualized right-click menu, Ctrl+F). But the more basic browser controls such as Refresh should never be overridden -- I remember when Twitter used to disable F5, presumably because of its auto-updating tweets list, but that was way too presumptuous. What if a resource fails to load and something appears broken? What if I want to reset the memory hog caused by the tweets list's infinite scroll? And for many other reasons, never disable refresh/F5.

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable refresh action of a browser. It's impossible.

If you need to remember something important you can use COOKIES or LocalStorage|SessionStorage to save data.

Answer (score 0):

To truly disable refresh you must use a server side script to check for page state changes

Try using a server-set cookie, such as PHP's $_SESSION, or even .Net's Response.Cookies, to     maintain "where" your client is in your site.